# Angular Typescript object property is clearly not undefined but property is

Tags: angular, typescript, undefined

I'm having a rather ridiculous problem.

An object from a subscribed observable has clearly data in it while printing it to the console, but in actual typescript code, says its undefined.

See for yourself:

```typescript
initData(): void {

    this.backendService.getData().subscribe((depotDays: DepotDayAcc[]) => {

      console.log(depotDays)
      console.log(depotDays[0])
      console.log(depotDays[0].investment)
      console.log(depotDays[0]["day"])

      console.log('depotDays[0] == undefined', depotDays[0] == undefined)
      console.log('depotDays[0].investment == undefined', depotDays[0].investment == undefined)
    })
}
```

[image]

```typescript
constructor(
    public day: Date,
    public investment: number = -1,
    public profit: number = 0,
    public value: number = 0,
    public percent: number = 0,
    public tickers: Set<string> = new Set<string>()) {
}
```

Comment: You haven't posted any details of the TypeScript message - namely **which line** you're referring to.

Comment: Is your data coming from `JSON.parse`? If so, then remember that your class `constructor` you posted **will not be invoked** - so those properties will not be set unless they're in the JSON. When using `JSON.parse` (without custom rehydration logic) you must use `interface` to describe the data you're expecting. (Indeed, the `tickers` member looks like an `Array<String>` to me, not a `Set` (otherwise Chrome would show `"tickers": Set(1)` instead of `["ADSK"]`.

Comment: Also, TypeScript's type system is based around _type erasure_: it's a essentially a glorified _practical_ compile-time type-prover: it is _not_ a runtime type-system - so whenever you use runtime type-assertions you lose the hard guarantees that TypeScript provides (and you have to use type-assertions with `JSON.parse` unless you write type-guards.

Comment: Because `depotDays[0]` is a string, not an object. Your backend is probably encoding it as json twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ShamPooSham has noted in his comment, your data is all strings. You have an array of strings, not objects.

```
const depotDay = JSON.parse(depotDays[0]);
console.log(depotDay.investment);
```

Choices are to either fix the payload so it gets deserialised properly, or to deserialise each entry yourself.